# How to make the UIWebView scroll smooth?

Tags: iphone

In my application ,I use the UIWebView to load a website's content,such is "http://www.apple.com",but i sroll the webview is not smooth, how can i to makt it more 
smooth ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t a magic wand here, but there are some things you can do to make it smoother:

- Use less memory. The more free memory, the better scrolling performance. Free what you can before displaying the web view. Also, be sure to implement `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` in your [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW4) subclasses, as well as in [your application delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW6). The [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/) can help.
- Don’t take advantage of the fact that `UIWebView` conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol. You may be tempted to monitor its scrolling activity, but everything you do will impact performance.

Comment: can any one give more suggestion??